# How to end / Force a close to a program (in Clojure)

Tags: clojure, exit

I am a pretty decent programmer in Java, however I am new to programming in Clojure.

In Java, to force an exit of a program, the code used is `System.exit(0)`. Is there any equivalent to this code is Clojure?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Given that part of the attractiveness of Clojure is that you can use Java class libraries, why not just do:

```
(System/exit 0)
```

Answer (score 8):

For a more complete reference, you call any Java classes static methods by specifying

```
(my.package.class/staticMethodName arg1 arg2 etc)
```

`java.lang.*` is loaded automagically for you already though if it where not you could call it with

```
(java.lang.System/exit 0)
```